# Can I style a 503 page?

Tags: vue.js, error-handling, http-status-code-503

I am currently working on a frontend component, that should display a 404 or a 503 error.

Anyway, I was wondering if it is even possible to display Text in the SPA if it is a 503. Since it is a Server error I cannot imagine, that is is possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can have your custom pages for each error. Using vue router and axios interceptors. 
Here's an article to read :

[Custom Error Pages based on API Response with Vue Router and Axios Response Interceptors](https://medium.com/@saulchelewani/custom-error-pages-with-vue-router-and-axios-response-interceptors-based-on-api-response-54ff1375376d)